# Contradiction in WeakReference's Java documentation

Tags: java, weak-references

This question is about understanding the Java documentation for WeakReference

When I read about Java's WeakReference, I came across this sentence in the documentation:

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in
>   time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will
>   atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak
>   references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that
>   object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references

But this doesn't make sense to me. Suppose I have a WeakReference wrA referencing an object A and another WeakReference wrB referencing an object B. And B strongly refers to A (directly or indirectly through a chain). Now according to the document, if A becomes weakly reachable and if B is already weakly reachable at that time, then wrB will be cleared together with wrA. However, since B is already weakly reachable at that time, shouldn't wrB already be cleared at an early time when the weak reachability of B is first detected?

Comment: *since B is already weakly reachable at that time* -- This fact may have gone undetected until now, no?

Comment: It may be a good idea to rephrase as seems difficult to get where is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since B is already weakly reachable at that time, shouldn't wrB already be cleared at an early time when the weak reachability of B is first detected?

This happens at the same time, so there is no earlier time.  When a GC starts all objects (e.g. both A and B) which are not strongly reachable at that time are eligible to be cleaned up at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's more of a presentation in the document. I'm just not convinced that detecting a weakly reachable object B that is on a path to another weakly reachable object A via first detecting A is better than just detecting B itself. But I have no idea about the graph algorithm that is used by GC and I think the implementation can choose whatever order it likes, efficient or not.

Comment: @user690421 The documentation is not specific about this and the JVM can chose any means which is appropriate. I suspect the distinction you are making is not useful and you end up with the same solution either way.  The point about A is that it can be cleaned up even though it has a strong reference to it because that comes via a weak reference.